# iPhone vibrates on every Viber text message received

Tags: iphone, applications, notifications, vibrate

Even when my viber application is open on a specific discussion, it continues to vibrate on every received message part of the current discussion.

How can I turn off this very annoying feature for Viber discussions ?

or, if not possible,

How can I turn off the whole Viber notifications vibration ?

I currently use an iPhone 5

Comment: Send feedback to the app maker... They choose it to work that way.

Comment: Do you want to turn off vibration on Viber for every message or only when you're in a discussion?

Comment: @fbara, I add a precision inside the question

Comment: Because, well, thats what it does when it receives a notification on silent..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the feedback has been acted upon, and it is now possible to turn off vibrations and sounds while you are using the app already. A very welcome change indeed! (Not sure which version it was implemented in) You can do it by going to "More" tab on Viber, and opening Settings -> Notifications, and turn off "In-App vibrations". See [the official Viber documentation here](https://support.viber.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1517474-making-changes-to-your-viber-settings-iphone-?b_id=3838#In-App%20Vibrate). Excerpt:

> **In-App Vibrate**
>
> When this option is enabled, you will receive a vibration for every incoming notification.

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that you can't turn off specific vibration notifications in Viber; that's just how the application is built.  I've seen messages on the Apple discussion boards with people complaining about this from almost 3 years ago.

To turn off all notifications for Viber, go into `Settings --> Notifications --> Viber`.  Switch the `Allow notifications` to off.  This will disable all notifications for Viber at the iPhone level.